# Add a second field category Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add a editable field for Category in Prestashop 1.7

I'm already do this :

Insert text_SEO in Database

**override/classes/Category.php**

```
<?php
class Category extends CategoryCore
{

public $text_SEO; // My Custom field

public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'category',
    'primary' => 'id_category',
    'multilang' => true,
    'multilang_shop' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        'nleft' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'nright' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'level_depth' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'required' => true),
        'id_parent' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'id_shop_default' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'is_root_category' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'position' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
        'date_add' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
        'date_upd' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),

        // Lang fields
        'name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCatalogName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
        'link_rewrite' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isLinkRewrite', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
        'description' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString'),
        'text_SEO' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString'),
        'meta_title' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 128),
        'meta_description' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'meta_keywords' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
    ),
);
}
```

**override/controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php**

```
    class AdminCategoriesController extends AdminCategoriesControllerCore
{
    public function renderForm()
    {
        $this->fields_form_override =array(
            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'label' => $this->l('Text SEO'),
                'name' => 'text_SEO',
                'lang' => true,
                'autoload_rte' => true,
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
            ),
        );
        return parent::renderForm();
    }
}
```

How can I display the areatext ?

Thank you ! :D

Comment: Try to remove a file app/cache/dev/class_index.php. It might be your problem. The file contains all information about classes and their overrides so it must be deleted after you added your override and will be regenerated during first page refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. This should work.

Did you add `text_SEO` in your database in table `category_lang` and not `category` ?
Did you empty your PrestaShop's cache before reloading your category page ? You can do that on Advanced parameters > Performance page